# Django trans template tag only displaying placeholder constant string

Tags: python, django, django-templates, internationalization, django-i18n

I have the following tag in `templates/home.html`:

```
{% trans "test" %}
```

Which always prints "test" no matter the language I choose. I know for a fact that the language changes because I print it like this (and the admin's language changes, etc...):

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}
```

In the project's settings.py I have:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# modeltranslation settings


LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('zh-hans', _('Simplified Chinese')),
    ('zh-hant', _('Traditional Chinese')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
]
```

I wanted to try out the translation to Simplified Chinese so I created the translation thing with `python3 manage.py makemessages -l zh-hans` and in `locale/zh-hans/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` I filled the value of `test` like this:

```
#: templates/home.html:8
msgid "test"
msgstr "你好"
```

Then I run `python3 manage.py compilemessages`.

In the `templates/_base.html` that `templates/home.html` inherits from, I have

```
{% load static %}
{% load static i18n %}
{% load i18n %}
```

and in `templates/home.html`, I have

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
```

Despite this, when I change the language to `zh-hans`, it always displays `test`. What could be wrong?

I am using django 3.0.1.

EDIT: In `settings.py`, I have switched from using `gettext` to `gettext_lazy` as `_` as suggested by a comment.

Comment: Where are you setting the language? Do you have `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` in your middleware setting?

Comment: I use something like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view and yes I have that middleware.

Comment: can you check what is the value of this "request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] " in one of your views

Comment: I believe you need to debug the value from `get_current_language` in your views, not on templates. And see what happens..

Comment: @nmfzone How do I do that? The documentation only mentions it as a tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#get-current-language

Comment: You can take a look on the core source code. If you're using good IDE, you'll easily navigate to that tag source code. It's just basically a wrapper of `from django.utils import translation` -> `translation.get_language()`

Comment: @nmfzone Thanks. Well when I print it inside the view, it gives me the expected result, `zh-hans` if I switched to simplified Chinese.

Comment: @Lag11 doing that also gives me the expected result, `zh-hans`.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem, but let me tell you something. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), it's said that you need to use gettext_lazy instead of gettext when you define custom Languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the locale folder has to be `zh_Hans` instead of `zh-hans`. That's what I get for not looking at the source code! https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth/locale